# How to fix those stretches ? / UV unwrapping

Tags: texturing, uv, uv-image-editor

[image]

How to fix those stretches ?
There's a blend file as well if needed

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you got n-gons that are "intersecting" with itself.
The easiest fix for that is to triangulate the faces that are causing problems.

[image: Overlapping UV]

Select the faces that are ngons and press

> ctrl + t

or search for Triangulate Faces

[image: Triangulaated Faces]